# Possible to draw on Multiple Canvas by ClassName?

Tags: javascript, canvas, getelementsbyclassname

From the below code I am passing values into my function with uses them to draw my specific shape. However when I try to get canvas by ClassName my code breaks and it says `.getContext()` is not a function. So here I am trying to find a way. With my current config I don't believe passing the actual document canvas object would be possible.

```
function drawShape1(topWidth, shadeHeight) {
   var canvas = document.getElementById('product-render-configurator');
   var paper  = canvas.getContext('2d');

   paper.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

   // begin custom shape
   paper.beginPath();
   //draw Shade String
   paper.moveTo(150, 0);
   paper.lineTo(150, 38);
   //draw shadeTop
   paper.moveTo( ( canvas.width / 2 ) - topWidth, 40 );
   paper.quadraticCurveTo( 150 , 35, ( canvas.width / 2 ) + topWidth, 40);
   paper.lineTo( ( canvas.width / 2 ) + topWidth, shadeHeight );
   paper.quadraticCurveTo( canvas.width / 2 , shadeHeight - 5, ( canvas.width / 2 ) - topWidth, shadeHeight);
   paper.lineTo( ( canvas.width / 2 ) - topWidth, 40 );
   paper.moveTo( (canvas.width / 2) - topWidth, shadeHeight );
   paper.quadraticCurveTo( canvas.width / 2 , shadeHeight + 5, ( canvas.width / 2 ) + topWidth, shadeHeight);

   // complete custom shape

   paper.lineWidth = 0.5;
   paper.strokeStyle = 'black';
   paper.stroke();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a HTMLCollection (an array-like object), so you can't directly call `.getContext()` on it. You have to loop over its elements and call `.getContext()` directly on each of them:

```
function drawShape1(topWidth, shadeHeight) {
   var canvases = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('class-name'));
   for (let canvas of canvases) {
     var paper  = canvas.getContext('2d');

     paper.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

     // begin custom shape
     paper.beginPath();
     //draw Shade String
     paper.moveTo(150, 0);
     paper.lineTo(150, 38);
     //draw shadeTop
     paper.moveTo( ( canvas.width / 2 ) - topWidth, 40 );
     paper.quadraticCurveTo( 150 , 35, ( canvas.width / 2 ) + topWidth, 40);
     paper.lineTo( ( canvas.width / 2 ) + topWidth, shadeHeight );
     paper.quadraticCurveTo( canvas.width / 2 , shadeHeight - 5, ( canvas.width / 2 ) - topWidth, shadeHeight);
     paper.lineTo( ( canvas.width / 2 ) - topWidth, 40 );
     paper.moveTo( (canvas.width / 2) - topWidth, shadeHeight );
     paper.quadraticCurveTo( canvas.width / 2 , shadeHeight + 5, ( canvas.width / 2 ) + topWidth, shadeHeight);

     // complete custom shape

     paper.lineWidth = 0.5;
     paper.strokeStyle = 'black';
     paper.stroke();
   }
 }
```